# How does Memcached deal with get/set operation under high concurrency?

Tags: database, caching, memcached, distributed-computing

I have learned that distributed cache system like Memcached can reduce the database load greatly by caching the common objects in the cache memory.And Memcached system uses LRU algorithm to eliminat outdated cached objects. The traditional LRU system is implemented by double linked list and hash-table. Every operation like get or set data will change the state of the LRU queue, so we must lock the queue first then do the operation, in high concurrency scenarios, locking overhead must be enormous.SO , i was wondering how the Memcached system works well under such circumstances? Thanks advance!